# Bootstrap - Aligning content in table header

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a web page that is using Bootstrap 3. In this web page, I am using a table with column headers. The column headers need to be centered. However, I also need to have a drop down menu in the upper-right corner of each column header. This last part is what's throwing everything off.

As you can see in this [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/wFywFzlOnz), my column headers aren't centered properly because of the drop down menu. That drop down menu isn't even positioned properly. I've tried using relative positioning, but apparently that doesn't work in a column header. My code looks like this:

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Name</th>
    <th class="text-center">
      <div>Chicago</div>
      <small class="text-muted">Illinois</small>
      <div class="pull-right">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="chicagoDropDownMenu" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
            <i>:</i>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right pull-right" aria-labelledby="chicagoDropDownMenu">
            <li><a href="#">Weather</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Visitors Guide</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Directions</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>      
    </th>
    <th class="text-center">
      <div>New York</div>
      <small class="text-muted">New York</small>
      <div class="pull-right">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="nyDropDownMenu" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
            <i>:</i>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right pull-right" aria-labelledby="nyDropDownMenu">
            <li><a href="#">Weather</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Visitors Guide</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Directions</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>            
    </th>    
    <th class="text-center">
      <div>San Francisco</div>
      <small class="text-muted">California</small>
      <div class="pull-right">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="sfDropDownMenu" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
            <i>:</i>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right pull-right" aria-labelledby="sfDropDownMenu">
            <li><a href="#">Weather</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Visitors Guide</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Directions</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>      
    </th>
  </tr></thead>
</table>
```

My question is, how do I position a drop down menu in the upper-right corner of a column header, and still center the rest of the content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use absolute positioning to make the text ignore the dropdown buttons. You can then move them around relative to their parent (the `th` tag). Note that you do need to give the `th` tag a position of `relative` for this to work:

CSS

```
.dropdown {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

th {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;    
}
```

**Note:** The red border is just there to help clarify what's going on.

Hope this helps!